# How to retrieve and save message details from gmail api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail-api

I am a bit stuck. I am trying to retrieve and display some gmail messages into my rails application. However, I think I am doing something wrong. My model is not working, neither is my controller. When I say not workign what I mean is I am unable to retrieve the message_ids and save them into my database. I am listing my code below. Please help point me to the right direction. Any help will be appreciated. I am a beginner programmer so please bear if my code sucks.

My model:

```
def self.from_gapi
  return if message_id.blank?
  # Initialize the API
  service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
  service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
  service.authorization = authorize

  response = service.execute(
    :api_method => gmail_api.users.messages.list,
    :parameters =>
                 {
                   'user_id' => 'me',
                   'q'       => 'query'
                   }).first_or_initialize.tap do |message|
  message.message_id = service.messages.list
  message.user_id    = auth.info.email
  #page token for if needed


  message.save!
  end
end
```

My Controller:

```
def new
  @messages = EmailImport.new
end

def create
  @messages = EmailImport.from_gapi(message_params)
  @messages.save!
puts messages
  #redirect_to #list the message_id path
else
  redirect_to about_path
  flash[:warning]   = "There was an error."
end

def index
  @messages = EmailImport.all
end
```

Comment: I think that providing the detail information about ``not working`` will help users think of your issue and solution.

Comment: I just edited... but the issue is that I am unable to retrieve the message_id  based on my query and save it into my database.

Comment: @user10443511 Please attach details of the error you are getting.

Comment: @elixir the error is the message_id not being automatically saved into my database table. There is no program error or anything, just the fact that my database table is empty despite my call to retrieve message_id from gmail. I hope this helps answer the error question.

Comment: @user10443511 Try using `pry` debugger to print your `@messages` object to console before you're saving it. If that's empty, the issue is with the logic for: `EmailImport.from_gapi(message_params)`. Hope this helps.